# Renderizando data.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, sql, json, nodejs, typescript

A veces cuando quiero renderizar información a tablas o cosas así me aparece esto:

> data.forEach is not a function

En esta ocasión estoy tratando de llenar un **breadcrumb** de **Bootstrap**, la cuestión es que casi siempre lleno tablas de esta manera, pero justo ahora no entiendo porque me aparece este error.

¿Alguien podría decirme que es lo que no estoy viendo?

**Lado Servidor**

```
router.get('/get-user/:id', (req, res) => {
    const {
        id
    } = req.params;

    const query = pool.query('SELECT * FROM USERS_ where id = ?', [id]);

    query.then((user)=>{

        res.json({user});
    }).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});
});
```

**Lado Cliente**

```
function getUserInfo() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/get-user/{{id_usercreated}}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: (data) => {
            data.forEach((item) => {
                const row = `
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">{{name}}</li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Creado por</li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item " aria-current="page">
                        <a herf="/get-user-edit/${ item.id}">${ item.username}</a>
                    </li>
                    `;
                $('#usercreatedinfo').append(row);
            });
        }
    });
    //$("#ownerT").load();
};

getUserInfo();
```

Gracias a todos por su tiempo.

Comment: `forEach` es una funcion especifica de Arrays.  El error significa que la variable `data` no contiene un array.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el output que da tu servidor? O sea, ell resultado de get '/get-user/{{id_usercreated}}'

Comment: @FernandoCarrascosa - 2:923 Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function - me dice.

Comment: Lo que quiero ver (o que pongas en el cuerpo de la respuesta) es cuál es lo que el Backend devuelve, para poder identificar el error

Comment: imprime lo que tiene data para poderte ayudar

Comment: No sé que librería usas exactamente para la consulta, imagino que [`mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) por la forma en que realizas la consulta a la DB, en todo caso debes tener en cuenta lo siguiente: 1.- Estás enviando datos en formato JSON desde el servidor. 2.- Estás esperando datos JSON (`dataType: 'json'`) en el lado cliente. Tomando en cuenta eso, el método [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) aplica a tipos `Array`, y se lo estás intentando aplicar a un Objeto de Javascript. Saludos

Comment: por lo menos intentaste hacer un `console.log(data);` para ver como te regresaba el response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si quitas los brackets {} en esta linea?

```
 res.json({user}); por  res.json(user);
```

user ya debiera ser un array en el then

Comment: Pues ya probé, pero el error persiste, cuando renderizo una vista y objeto json siempre el objeto lo mando entre { }

Comment: podrias añadir un console.log(user) (en el then) y console.log(data) en el success  y mostrar un pantallazo de ambos? asi puedo identificar q contienen esas variables.   porque.. conjeturando quizas, tengas q entrar como data[0].forEach